# Why is buffer return null in this example?

Tags: android, android-layout, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is the node on Firebase database:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxEo4.png]

This is a code to retrieve data of trip:

```
database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        myRef = database.getReference(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    TripAddData value = (TripAddData) data.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("Trips").child("13").child("tripName").getValue();
                    buffer.append(value+"#");
                    System.out.println(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
                }
                System.out.println(buffer.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                // Failed to read value
                Log.w("****", "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
            }
        });
```

Why buffer return of null?

Comment: Where is your buffer definition before buffer.append()?

Comment: in onCreate(); , it just buffer=new StringBuffer();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing this:

```
TripAddData value = (TripAddData) data.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("Trips").child("13").child("tripName").getValue();
```

With this:

```
String value = data.child("Trips").child("13").child("tripName").getValue(String.class);
```

I can't help you with the casting to a TripAddData without seeing what that actually is. But this should at least return something.